# Multiplication in terms of addition

Tags: lisp, scheme

Given the following task:

> **Exercise 1.17**
>
> The exponentiation
>   algorithms in this section are based
>   on performing exponentiation by means
>   of repeated multiplication. In a
>   similar way, one can perform integer
>   multiplication by means of repeated
>   addition. The following multiplication
>   procedure (in which it is assumed that
>   our language can only add, not
>   multiply) is analogous to the expt
>   procedure:
>
> ```
> (define (* a b)
>   (if (= b 0)
>       0
>       (+ a (* a (- b 1)))))
> ```
>
> This algorithm takes a number of steps
>   that is linear in b. Now suppose we
>   include, together with addition,
>   operations double, which doubles an
>   integer, and halve, which divides an
>   (even) integer by 2. Using these,
>   design a multiplication procedure
>   analogous to fast-expt that uses a
>   logarithmic number of steps.

I wrote this solution:

```
(define (double a) (* a 2))
(define (halve a) (/ a 2))
(define (even n) (= (remainder n 2) 0))

(define (times a b)
  (cond ((= 1 b) a)
        ((even b) (times (double a) (halve b)))
        (else (times (+ a a) (- b 1)))))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation will not produce correct results in general.

In the base case of b = 0, result should be 0.  In the case of even b, result is double a times half b (which you have done correctly).  In the case of odd b, result should be a + (double a times half (b - 1)).

```
(define (times a b)
  (cond ((= 0 b) 0)
        ((even b) (times (double a) (halve b)))
        (else (+ a (times (double a) (halve (- b 1)))))))
```

To make this definition iterative, add an accumulator, like so:

```
(define (times a b)
  (times-iter 0 a b))

(define (times-iter acc a b)
  (cond ((= 0 b) acc)
        ((even b) (times-iter acc (double a) (halve b)))
        (else (times-iter (+ a acc) (double a) (halve (- b 1))))))
```

Comment: How would you write this as an iterative solution, as per exercise 1.18 on http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html ?

Comment: @jaresty: Edited my answer to include an iterative solution.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between recursive and iterative?

Comment: @jaresty:  Recursion is the process of solving a problem by restating it in terms of a smaller example of the same problem.  This is usually done by calling a procedure from within itself, with arguments that tend toward the base cases, and passing back the results of the call in order to build a solution.  Iteration is the process of rerunning a collection of statements with changing variables until a terminating condition is met.  Iteration may be implemented in a number of ways: as a loop or, in the case of Scheme, as a tail-call optimized recursion.